# How to interact with page with ready status as Interactive in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

It's a strange application and I am facing lots of challenges in automating this application using Selenium WebDriver.

**Problem**

Issue is that even after the page gets completed loaded, the document.readyState state of the page always shows the value as Interactive and due to which Selenium does not sends the control to the next line after performing the given action and it keeps on waiting for the page document.readyState to be change to complete which never happens.

Is there any way through which I can force Selenium not to wait for the page document.readyState to change to complete? I know it's Selenium default behavior but is there anything which can be done?

**Workaround but facing other challenge:-**

For common actions like click...I know we can use Javascript click instead of Selenium click, JS click does not wait for the page status. I am using JS click which is working pretty fine but now there is a scenario where on clicking of link I need to switch to new window. I don't think there is any function in JS which allows us to switch to new window and now I am forced to use Selenium switch to new window functionality which is getting stuck due to above problem. Is there anyway where I can change the page document.readyState to complete forcefully?

**Forgot to mention that this issue is only in IE, it works pretty fine in Chrome.**

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to edit the code of the appliation you are testing?

Comment: No, don't have access to code. It's a client application.

Comment: Then it does not apply to my case which i tell anyway: I had some problems with javascript errors and selenium testing. When I fixed them selenium tests ran. The problem you describe I also encountered when lots of js was executed on page load. I eventually added some hidden html element to the page, after everything was loaded and made selenium wait for that element to start running several tests

Comment: I don't suppose you can post a link to the page? You can try using `sendKeys()` and send an `Esc` key to the page. That should stop the page from loading but it could put the page in a bad state depending on what all has loaded.

Comment: @JeffC Page is already loaded, it's just that the Page document.readyState property is still showing as Interactive (Guess due to some internal JS error). I tried to send ESC key but still the value is coming as Interactive for Page document.readyState property.

Comment: are you trying to test SignalR application?

Comment: No it is just a basic web application.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page? If it's a client application, have you informed them of the issue to have them fix it? You should be able to open the dev console and see any JS errors while the page is loading.

Comment: It's a client application and yes we are going to inform them about the issue but that will take some time to get fix.

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/999#issuecomment-201027047) may be relevant. It concerns the `readyState` not transitioning to `complete` if there's is an info bar (in IE).

> The proper way to resolve the issue now is to set the `pageLoadStrategy` capability to the value of "eager". In the .NET bindings at least, this can be done by setting the value of `InternetExplorerOptions.PageLoadStrategy` to `InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager`. Other language bindings should consult their documentation on how to set desired capabilities for the IE driver. Furthermore, please do understand that this might have side effects on waiting for pages to load after navigation, so do take care to make sure you are properly waiting for elements on the resulting page.

Even if your issue is not caused by an info bar changing the page load strategy to "eager" might still work for you. In Java it should work like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, "eager");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I am trying to use InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions(); in Java but seems like it does not have any method for same in Java.

Comment: Apologies for responding late but I was unable to test the above code as the given application is no more accessible to us. I have voted your answer as it looks promising. Thanks for the help.